# Add checkbox with button in ASP - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creting this webapp where I need to add data to the checkboxes after confirming with a button, but I also need to make it create automatic checkbox when it is clicked. What can I use to add that fuction?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Add some code to your question so that it will be easier for others to understand your question.

Comment: There is a detailed explaination of dynamically adding the controls https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan Here is what it happens when you click the button, it sends the information from text boxe to the checkbox.

`CheckBoxLinhas.Text = "Quantidade: " + TextBoxQuantidade.Text + " Artigo: " + TextBoxArtigo.Text + " Valor: " + TextBoxValor.Text;`

Now I want to add more checkboxes after that, so you can add multiple things.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough though. Are you trying to add dynamic checkbox?

Comment: @SamyuktaR. yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this as follows:

```
    <div id="chkList">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox1" id="chk1" /> 
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <input type="button" value="Add" id="btnSave" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnSave').click(function() {
            addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
        });
    });

    function addCheckbox(name) {
       var element= $('#chkList');
       var input = element.find('input');
       var id = input.length +1;        
       $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'chk'+id, value: name }).appendTo(element);          
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry for my really noob question, but it is one of my first time with ASP.NET, I add that code to the button in aspx.cs?

Comment: It's Jquery code, you should write this code on your aspx page not in aspx.cs.

Comment: I've found an easier way to do it with aspx.cs, but you need to use a `CheckBoxList` instead.